# Icons disappears after reinstallation of the application

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, icons

Every time I reinstall my application after some modifications to my version my icons disappear such as like button ,note button, menutab and etc. However after running the application for the second time they reapear as usual. What can be the cause for that sort of bag?